# Sharepoint Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Getting error

> SharePoint server or SharePoint foundation not installed on the
>   machine

while creating empty project in visual studio community 15. can anyone help

Comment: Is your host machine have SharePoint server or SharePoint foundation installed?

Answer (score 0):

Installation of SharePoint is required on the machine on which you are running visual studio to Create SharePoint template projects like Empty SharePoint Project and few more.

While creating SharePoint Add-In (Previously SharePoint App) you need not to have SharePoint server installation on the same machine. SharePoint Add-In's are meant to be for non server related development.